# Should I fillna missing data before or after conducting null hypothesis and anova test?

Tags: machine-learning, anova, python, missing-data

My dataset have a lot of nan values. And i also want to conduct `Null hypothesis` and `ANOVA` on my categorical data to see the correlation on saleprice.

Check features with missing values:

```
total = df_data.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
percent = (df_data.isnull().sum()/df_data.isnull().count()).sort_values(ascending=False)
missing_data = pd.concat([total, percent], axis=1, keys=['Total', 'Percent'])
missing_data.head(20)
```

[image]

I was wondering which process should I do first?

- OPTION 1: Fill missing data --> Null Hypo & ANOVA
- OPTION 2: Null Hypo & ANOVA --> Fill missing data.

**Edit:**

I tried OPTION 2 and got these results from anova:

**Is it normal to have nan values for f & p values for some categorical variables?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: You should not fill the missing data when doing a hypothesis test.  If you fill in the missing data, you will be biasing the results.  Simply remove the missing data before performing the test.

Comment: Define a lot of missing values.

Comment: @user2974951 Missing values are nan values in dataset

Comment: Yes, but what percentage of NA values do you have in each column?

Comment: @DemetriPananos I have updated my results and I'm not sure if its the right way. Please guide me.

Comment: @user2974951 I have uploaded the  results of percentages of NA values. Please take a look.

Comment: A standard dataset from Kaggle. There are many tutorials on the House dataset. The variables with high NA should definitely get removed. You could for ex. impute with multiple imputations, run a test on each dataset.

Comment: Can you post the dataset? I can get to it ofay